# How can I export Excel cells to specific HTML tags?

Tags: html, excel

I would like to ask if there is a way to export data from excel cells and fill specific tags in an html document.

For example, lets say a cell in the Excel document has the price of the product, I would like to export it and add it in a specific area in the HTML document named #product_price for example.

Anyone knows a way?

Thanks for your time,

Bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start here: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
Remember there are limitations to the sizes of sheets it can read, which seems to be about 80000 cells.  If you exceed that (or if you don't want to use a 3rd party library, or you want faster performance) convert the excel sheets to CSV and use PHP's `fgetcsv` function: http://www.php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: Hello mate and thanks for your time. After some research I think I will use XSL and XML.